# If id1 is primary key in table t1. And I want to create new table t2 and use id1 in t1 as foreign key in t2. What should be my query?

Tags: mysql

If `id1` is primary key in table `t1`. And I want to create new table `t2` and use id1 in `t1` as foreign key in `t2`. What should be my query? 
Is this one right?

```
create table t2(id2 int primary key, id1 int references t1(id1));
```

Comment: Please just check the documentation to see how to do this.  Any tutorial site would probably do fine.

Comment: Did you receive an error? Does something not look correct to you? Details of either of these would enhance the question. As it is, it's "please, strangers on the internet, do the work that my database system can do for me in a few minutes and I can *validate* my own approach"

Answer (score 0):

1. In the first step create a second table:

   create table t2(id2 int primary key)
2. In next step we add constraint between t1 and t2. **Constraint** section is only name - you can use your own definition; **foreign key** is column name to connect with table; **references** section is indicate table and column to connect by foreign key.

   ALTER TABLE t2 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES t1(id1);

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

please read this documentation for learning more about foreign key constraint
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

for your case is below

```
create table t1(id1 int primary key);

create table t2(id2 int , CONSTRAINT FK_t1 FOREIGN KEY (id2)
    REFERENCES t1(id1));
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c6c03

Comment: @pankaz if it helps please accept anawer for so appriciation